# Why does my font look different?

Tags: html, css

I am using the CGF Locust Resistance Font that I got from dafont.com This is how the font is supposed to look: http://www.dafont.com/cgf-locust-resistance.font and this is how it looks on my webpage: https://postimg.org/image/r2a1xcxun/

As you can see the letters look more squashed in, particularly noticeable on the "F" , "A" and "E". Here is my CSS and HTML code. Anybody have any idea why it is like this?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gears Of War</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1>GEARS OF WAR</h1>
</header>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

header {
font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
letter-spacing: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 28px;
color: lightgray;
text-shadow:
-1.5px -1.5px 0 black,  
 1.5px -1.5px 0 black,
-1.5px  1.5px 0 black,
 1.5px  1.5px 0 black;
}
```

Font face declaration:

```
@font-face {
font-family: cgf_locust_resistanceregular;
src: url('Downloads/cgf_locust_resistance-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('Downloads/cgf_locust_resistance-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Could be a problem with the font itself or with the way the browser renders the font. In FF and Safari it looks ok here, in Chrome it does not.

Comment: I tried it in FF and it looks the same for me

Comment: Can you post your font-face declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the fact that the *h1* tag has a default browser style that forces the font-weight to **bold**. Try to set font-weight to normal for the h1 tag and the problem should be gone.

The font probably don't play well with bold styling.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
font-family: "CGF Locust Resistance";
```

If a font name contains white-space, it must be **quoted**. 
Side-note: Single quotes must be used when using the **"style"** attribute in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

"dafont.com" provided "CGF Locust Resistance.ttf" file. So, you need to generate this font to get (woff and woff2) file. You can generate this from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Then you put thos font file in your fonts folder and need to call those in your css file. I make a video to show the full process. See the video I think your concept will be clear.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV1-VEAmM-0&feature=youtu.be

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cgf_locust_resistanceregular';
    src: url('fonts/cgf_locust_resistance-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/cgf_locust_resistance-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

header {
font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
letter-spacing: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 28px;
color: lightgray;
text-shadow:
-1.5px -1.5px 0 black,  
 1.5px -1.5px 0 black,
-1.5px  1.5px 0 black,
 1.5px  1.5px 0 black;
}
```

Comment: @Cian have you tried opening autogenerated cgf_locust_resistance-demo.html ? This looks good for me in Chrome.

Comment: eh where do i get that from

Comment: Please follow the video. In this video I show the full process to use this fonts. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV1-VEAmM-0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Put your font name in single quote like this font-family: 'CGF Locust Resistance' as because there is a space in your font name.

Comment: While I agree that quotes should be used here, the image shows that the correct font is use by the browser the OP tests the font in. So adding quotes would not solve the problem, that the font is not rendered correctly (the gaps that are to small).

Comment: Quotes are necessary otherwise the browser will misinterpret because of the whitespace, it will be expecting a comma.

Comment: Then you could try adding normalized style sheet which you can get from this [link](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)

Comment: @RossKeddy I didn't disagree about the quotes. I just pointed out, that the screenshot of the OP shows that the font was used correctly by the browser  even though the quotes are missing. So even if the OP fixes that - what the OP definitely should - the problem will still remain.

Comment: @RossKeddy Problem still remains :/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's because you have your characters in uppercase, the characters with particles comes into effect when lowercase characters are used, atleast according to the font specifications.
http://puu.sh/r6Ibi/31f3fc195a.png